React Native Expo - How to go to the sitemap page?
I cannot find a button to the sitemap page anywhere else except the 404 page, the page is shown when expo-router failed to match a route. It's not convenience for I need to go to the page that is under development quickly, without being able to go to the sitemap I have to add additional links in the Home page.

I had the same thought while developing a new app and new pages within the app. Dug into a bit, read through the docs and skimmed some articles but didn't find anything like a quick keyboard shortcut or link from the developer menu / devtools. So instead I just added the following to an element always shown in the header...
  <Pressable
    style={{
      width: 48,
      height: 32,
      borderRadius: 10,
      backgroundColor: theme.placeholder,
    }}
    onLongPress={() => router.push(__DEV__ ? '/_sitemap' : '/')}
  />

This just allows me to long press that logo (an event I wouldn't use for any other interaction in that element) in order to get to the sitemap if I'm in development mode. Otherwise (e.g. in production), it'll just direct me to the homepage.
